# how to invoke a bootstrap twitter modal? from a user/show page i am trying to call contact_mail_deliveries/new html erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am some how not able to invoke this modal...nothing happens when I click the button

user/show.html.erb has the following snippet

```
     <div class="row padding5">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
       <%= link_to "CONTACT USER",      new_contact_mail_delivery_path(listing_id: listing.id), {:remote => true,, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#Mymodal' :class => "btn btn-primary"} %>
      </div>
     </div>
```

and in my contact_mail_deliveries/new.html.erb

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

  modal code...

 </div>
```

please help with how to proceed over this, I am a newbie to coding.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. Check that you have added the javascript file for bootstrap too -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

add these at the end of your html code.

Check out the demo at http://divyavrat.github.io/modal/